# Concurrency and django scaling horizontal

Tags: django, django-models, concurrency, django-celery

Hello I would like to ask you for advice for an application, I currently use Django cookie cutter for the project, I use as a library, Django MPTT in this model it must respect a certain hierarchy and that some objects do not find themselves in the same place as another to do this I need to isolate the objects to then perform my calculation and create my new objects. First of all since it could take a while I used Cellery to make my additions to the database I tried several concurrent accesses and I never had a rollback, I thought instead of using Cellery since I know how to scale the docker into several Django, I would integrate this creation into my view and use the @atomic decorator. The problem is that when we create objects at the same time on each different server (django1,django2,django3) I have a lot of rollback while with celeriac I have no problem. I don't understand why competition is more difficult in Django than in celery? Do you have any advice for me? For a better management of different Django servers at the same time, thank you in advance example :

Work in celery norollback :

```
@celery_app.task()
    def create_user_in_matrix(user_id):
         .....
     new_human = HumanFaction.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=int(user_id))
        with transaction.atomic():
            new_human = new_human.first()
            alderol = HumanFaction.objects.get(user_id=alderol_user_id)
            print('selection utilisateur', new_human)
            level = 1
            level_max = HumanFaction.objects.aggregate(Max('level'))['level__max']
            if level_max == 0:
                level_max = 1
            print('level maximum', level_max)
            while level <= level_max and user_whole:
                users = HumanFaction.objects.select_for_update().filter(level=level)
                HumanFaction.objects.create(user=new_human, parent=aledol)
                 .....
```

Operates every third time in a django view during a colision test frequent rollback (django,1,2,3)

```
@transaction.atomic
def human_group(request):
...... 
new_human = HumanFaction.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=int(user_id))
        with transaction.atomic():
            new_human = new_human.first()
            alderol = HumanFaction.objects.get(user_id=alderol_user_id)
            print('selection utilisateur', new_human)
            level = 1
            level_max = HumanFaction.objects.aggregate(Max('level'))['level__max']
            if level_max == 0:
                level_max = 1
            print('level maximum', level_max)
            while level <= level_max and user_whole:
                users = HumanFaction.objects.select_for_update().filter(level=level)
                HumanFaction.objects.create(user=new_human, parent=aledol)
            .....
```

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. You talk about "rollback" but in the code you show I can't see anything that would result in any sql insert or update

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @heyhugo :) Here I modified the code to give an additional example, this one is really very long and therefore split for more readability

Comment: Ok, I think you're leaving out details still needed to be of any help. For example if a rollback occurred it'd be due to some error right e.g IntegrityError or something else? Is using `select_for_update` a conscious choice here, do you know what it means? Otherwise read up on it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: hank you for your answer, I finally left the task in celery and did a retry if it triggers an error in the creation, what I wanted was to block access to the database during the calculation, free the lock so that the next one could have the right information and not duplicate in the hierarchy, so I split in two, I get the proof of payment, then I register the user in the group with celery he tests the addition several times by looking at the entirety, if unfortunately there is a problem he goes back and retests the creation of it, then he confirms that the payment is well >>>

Comment: >>> associated with this user, if the task fails too many times I block the user's account and I get sent an email so that I can manage the problem manually :) @heyhugo